# webservices : how to initialise javax.xml.ws.Holder

Tags: web-services

I am new for webservices. I want to know how to use

> javax.xml.ws.Holder

Any one pl help me

Thanks

Comment: Please give more details. What do you want to accomplish via Holder? What have you tried with it? (Post some sample code?) What problem have you encountered? If you just want to know basic usage of Holder, just google it and there are quite a few articles related to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo(@WebParam(name = "flag", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Boolean> flag)
```

then in the foo body

```
flag.value=true;
```